# dplyr fill in group using preferential list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table that looks similar to

```
ID, value

1, NA
1, Positive
1, Negative
1, NA
2, NA
2, Absent
2, Negative
2, NA
...
```

I want to mutate another column on the end of this which has the "most positive" (defined in order "Positive">"Negative">"Absent">"Not Done">NA) in each group (grouped by ID)

I can add a column and use fill, but this can give multiple values in the additional column

```
df <- df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(summary_value = value) %>%
 fill(summary_value, .direction="updown") %>%
 ungroup()
```

which gives

```
ID, value, summary_value

1, NA, Positive
1, Positive, Positive
1, Negative, Negative
1, NA, Negative
2, NA, Absent
2, Absent, Absent
2, Negative, Negative
2, NA, Negative
...
```

What I would like is a dplyr code that will return

```
ID, value, summary_value

1, NA, Positive
1, Positive, Positive
1, Negative, Positive
1, NA, Positive
2, NA, Negative
2, Absent, Negative
2, Negative, Negative
2, NA, Negative
...
```

so that the ID & summary_value pairs can be deduplicated (among other columns)

I am using dplyr v1.1.1 and tidyr v1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or this:

```
df%>%
  mutate(summary_value=case_when("Positive" %in% value ~ "Positive",
                                 "Negative" %in% value ~ "Negative",
                                 "Absent" %in% value ~ "NegatAbsentive",
                                 "Not Done" %in% value ~ "Not Done",
                                 TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         .by=ID)

  ID    value summary_value
1  1     <NA>      Positive
2  1 Positive      Positive
3  1 Negative      Positive
4  1     <NA>      Positive
5  2     <NA>      Negative
6  2   Absent      Negative
7  2 Negative      Negative
8  2     <NA>      Negative
```

Comment: This seems to work, and also returns "NA" if all the values are NA within the group

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels = c("Positive", "Negative", "Absent"))) %>% 
 mutate(summary_value = first(levels(droplevels(value))), .by = ID)
```

-output

```
 ID    value summary_value
1  1     <NA>      Positive
2  1 Positive      Positive
3  1 Negative      Positive
4  1     <NA>      Positive
5  2     <NA>      Negative
6  2   Absent      Negative
7  2 Negative      Negative
8  2     <NA>      Negative
```

Comment: This doesn't work if all the "value"s in the group are NA